# ReactJS when user scrolls down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

With React, what is the proper way to make functions on scroll?

For example if user scrolls 500px from the top I would like console to log something. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use DOM to set up a scroll event listener. Take this example:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
  }

  onScroll() {
    var scrollY = window.scrollY;
    if (scrollY === 500) {
        console.log(`Scrolled ${scrollY} px`);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <div>Some content</div>
        { this.props.children }
      <main>
    );
  }
}
```

This code example should give you a good idea on where to take your app. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely want to subscribe to the [`scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) event on `window`.

To attach a listener, you are going to call `addEventListener` and pass it a function:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', someFunction);
```

Now, as to when React comes into play, you will probably want to attach the listener in the `componentDidMount` hook of your top-level component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind();
  },

  handleScroll(evt) {
    const fromTop = window.scrollY;
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  },

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }
}
```